# Javascript for multiple file conversion in Adobe Acrobat failing

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to convert multiple files from PDF to plain text in Adobe. I found a solution online that reads:

```
/* PDF to Text */



this.saveAs("C:\Users\sandr\Dropbox\Light\Doctorate\Supervisor meetings\2018\October\Method\test_corpus\2sleep.tar\2sleep\2sleep\pdf\txt_output" + this.documentFileName + ".txt","com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text");
```

The script runs but it always gives an error saying it could not open the file and it doesn't actually create the text file. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Because Acrobat Javascript needs to run on both Mac and Windows, you need to use platform independent paths. Windows-specific file names and paths won't work. For example...

```
this.saveAs("C/Users/user/Dropbox/foo.pdf");
```

Also...

```
this.documentFileName
```

will have a ".pdf" extension at the end, you may want to trim that before appending the ".txt"

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have tried doing this but I get ther same error message which is "File open failed" and it doesn't save the file...

Comment: The folder has to exist. Acrobat won't just create it for you and the field name needs to be valid.